# Sorting space delimited numbers with Linux/Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a Linux utility or a Bash command I can use to sort a space delimited string of numbers?

Comment: [Very related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648410/how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-an-array-in-bash).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a simple example to get you going:

`echo "81 4 6 12 3 0" | tr " " "\n" | sort -g`

`tr` translates the spaces delimiting the numbers, into carriage returns, because sort uses carriage returns as delimiters (ie it is for sorting **lines** of text). The `-g` option tells sort to sort by "general numerical value".

`man sort` for further details about `sort`.

Comment: I appended another `| tr` with the parameters reversed to get a space delimited string back out.

Comment: To reverse the sort, use `-r`.

Comment: To output the result with spaces: `echo \`echo "81 4 6 12 3 0" | tr " " "\n" | sort -g | tr "\n" " "\``

Answer (score 15):

This is a variation from @JamesMorris answer:

```
echo "81 4 6 12 3 0" | xargs -n1 | sort -g | xargs
```

Instead of `tr`, I use `xargs -n1` to convert to new lines. The final `xargs` is to convert back, to a space separated sequence of numbers.

Comment: This is super handy, but why oh why do `xargs -n1` and `xargs` do that?

Comment: `xargs` by default (if no utility specified) uses `echo` on the input and the rest it's just about how it handles arguments: `-n1` it's max one per invocation.

Answer (score 4):

This is a variation on **ghostdog74's** answer that's too big to fit in a comment. It shows digits instead of names of numbers and both the original string and the result are in space-delimited strings (instead of an array which becomes a newline-delimited string).

```
$ s="3 2 11 15 8"
$ sorted=$(echo $(printf "%s\n" $s | sort -n))
$ echo $sorted
2 3 8 11 15
$ echo "$sorted"
2 3 8 11 15
```

If you didn't use the `echo` when setting the value of `sorted`, then the string has newlines in it. In that case echoing it without quotes puts it all on one line, but, as echoing it with quotes would show, each number would appear on its own line. This is the case whether the original is an array or a string.

```
# demo
$ s="3 2 11 15 8"
$ sorted=$(printf "%s\n" $s | sort -n)
$ echo $sorted
2 3 8 11 15
$ echo "$sorted"
2
3
8
11
15
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ s=(one two three four)
$ sorted=$(printf "%s\n" ${s[@]}|sort)
$ echo $sorted
four one three two
```

Comment: `$ sorted=` **`(`** `$(printf "%s\n" ${s[@]}|sort)` **`)`**   defines sorted as an array of values again, but sorted

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash parameter expansion (to replace spaces with newlines) we can do:

```
str="3 2 11 15 8" 
sort -n <<< "${str// /$'\n'}"

# alternative
NL=$'\n'
str="3 2 11 15 8"
sort -n <<< "${str// /${NL}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my `.zshrc` (or `.bashrc`) file:

```sh
#sort a space-separated list of words (e.g. a list of HTML classes)
sortwords() {
  echo $1 | xargs -n1 | sort -g | xargs
}
```

Call it from the terminal like this:

```sh
sortwords "banana date apple cherry"

# apple banana cherry date
```

Thanks to @FranMowinckel and others for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have a space-delimited string of numbers, then one of the other answers provided would work fine. If your list is a bash array, then:

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(sort -g <<< "${array[*]}"))
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

might be a better solution. The newline delimiter would help if you want to generalize to sorting an array of strings instead of numbers.

Comment: my list is a bash array, but this isn't working for me: `packages="$(sort <<< ${!package2apk[@]})"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split(ARGV[1], numbers);for(i in numbers) {print numbers[i]} }' \
     "6 7 4 1 2 3" | sort -n
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Evan Krall's nice Bash "array sort" by limiting the scope of IFS to a single command:

```
printf "%q\n" "${IFS}"
array=(3 2 11 15 8) 
array=($(IFS=$'\n' sort -n <<< "${array[*]}")) 
echo "${array[@]}" 
printf "%q\n" "${IFS}"
```