# How can I get unique values from an array in Bash?

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, unique

I've got almost the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618378/select-unique-or-distinct-values-from-a-list-in-unix-shell-script).

I have an array which contains `aa ab aa ac aa ad`, etc.
Now I want to select all unique elements from this array.
Thought, this would be simple with `sort | uniq` or with `sort -u` as they mentioned in that other question, but nothing changed in the array...
The code is:

```
echo `echo "${ids[@]}" | sort | uniq`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

A bit hacky, but this should do it:

```
echo "${ids[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
```

To save the sorted unique results back into an array, do [Array assignment](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2178):

```
sorted_unique_ids=($(echo "${ids[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '))
```

If your shell supports [herestrings](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) (`bash` should), you can spare an `echo` process by altering it to:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${ids[@]}" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
```

**A note as of Aug 28 2021:**

According to [ShellCheck wiki 2207](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207) a `read -a` pipe should be used to avoid splitting.
Thus, in bash the command would be:

`IFS=" " read -r -a ids <<< "$(echo "${ids[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')"`

or

`IFS=" " read -r -a ids <<< "$(tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${ids[@]}" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')"`

**Input:**

```
ids=(aa ab aa ac aa ad)
```

**Output:**

```
aa ab ac ad
```

**Explanation:**

- `"${ids[@]}"` - Syntax for working with shell arrays, whether used as part of `echo` or a herestring. The `@` part means "all elements in the array"
- `tr ' ' '\n'` - Convert all spaces to newlines. Because your array is seen by shell as elements on a single line, separated by spaces; and because sort expects input to be on separate lines.
- `sort -u` - sort and retain only unique elements
- `tr '\n' ' '` - convert the newlines we added in earlier back to spaces.
- `$(...)` - [Command Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)
- Aside: `tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${ids[@]}"` is a more efficient way of doing: `echo "${ids[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n'`

Comment: +1. A bit tidier: store uniq elements in a new array: `uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${ids[@]}" | sort -u)); echo  "${uniq[@]}"`

Comment: @glennjackman oh neat! I didn't even realize you can use `printf` that way (give more arguments than format strings)

Comment: Yes, the format string gets reused until all the arguments are consumed -- it's very handy

Comment: +1 to sampson-chen for the explanation in your post.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if this is an isolated case, but putting unique items back into an array needed additional parentheses such as: `sorted_unique_ids=($(echo "${ids[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '))`. Without the additional parentheses it was giving it as a string.

Comment: @sampson-chen: you could edit your answer including suggestions from glenn jackman and Michael!

Comment: This solution doesn't work with empty values (""), that get skipped at best, or that may add unwanted spaces. Build a script based on [array iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/2227298) if you have empty values in your input array.

Comment: If you don't want to alter the order of the elements, use `... | uniq | ...` instead of `... | sort -u | ...`.

Comment: @Jesse, `uniq` only removes _consecutive_ duplicates. In the example in this answer, `sorted_unique_ids` will end up identical to the original `ids`. To preserve order, try `... | awk '!seen[$0]++'`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix.

Comment: If you're assigning back to a variable, you can leave out the `| tr '\n' ' '` part, as the subshell already strips the output of any newline characters by default ( if there are no quotes around the subshell command `$(...)` ).

Comment: -1: This breaks array elements containing a space into multiple values, which (to me) is one of the main benefits of using arrays over simple space-delimited strings.

Answer (score 43):

If you're running Bash version 4 or above (which should be the case in any modern version of Linux), you can get unique array values in bash by creating a new associative array that contains each of the values of the original array.  Something like this:

```
$ a=(aa ac aa ad "ac ad")
$ declare -A b
$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do b["$i"]=1; done
$ printf '%s\n' "${!b[@]}"
ac ad
ac
aa
ad
```

This works because in any array (associative or traditional, in any language), each key can only appear once.  When the `for` loop arrives at the second value of `aa` in `a[2]`, it overwrites `b[aa]` which was set originally for `a[0]`.

Doing things in native bash can be faster than using pipes and external tools like `sort` and `uniq`, though for larger datasets you'll likely see better performance if you use a more powerful language like awk, python, etc.

If you're feeling confident, you can avoid the `for` loop by using `printf`'s ability to recycle its format for multiple arguments, though this seems to require `eval`. (Stop reading now if you're fine with that.)

```
$ eval b=( $(printf ' ["%s"]=1' "${a[@]}") )
$ declare -p b
declare -A b=(["ac ad"]="1" [ac]="1" [aa]="1" [ad]="1" )
```

The reason this solution requires `eval` is that array values are determined before word splitting. That means that the output of the command substitution is considered *a single word* rather than a set of key=value pairs.

While this uses a subshell, it uses only bash builtins to process the array values. Be sure to evaluate your use of `eval` with a critical eye. If you're not 100% confident that chepner or glenn jackman or greycat would find no fault with your code, use the for loop instead.

Comment: produces error: expression recursion level exceeded

Comment: @Benubird - can you perhaps pastebin your terminal contents?  It works perfectly for me, so my best guess is that you've got (1) a typo, (2) an older version of bash (associative arrays were added to v4), or (3) a ridiculously large influx of cosmic background radiation caused by the quantum black hole in your neighbour's basement, generating interference with the signals within your computer.

Comment: can't, didn't keep the one that didn't work. but, I tried running yours just now and it worked, so probably the cosmic radiation thing.

Comment: guessing that this answer utilizes bash v4 (associative arrays) and if someone tries in bash v3 it wont work (probably not what @Benubird saw).  Bash v3 is still default in many envs

Comment: @nhed ... It does indeed require bash v4.  I admit, my knowledge of bash version distribution is limited...  What modern systems still ship with bash v3?

Comment: @ghoti my mac book is from late last year and the default shell is ```$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```  still I like this answer best but has a portability issue

Comment: @nhed, point taken. I see that my up-to-date Yosemite Macbook has the same version in base, though I've installed v4 from macports.  This question is tagged "linux", but I've updated my answer to point out the requirement.

Answer (score 29):

I realize this was already answered, but it showed up pretty high in search results, and it might help someone.

```
printf "%s\n" "${IDS[@]}" | sort -u
```

Example:

```
~> IDS=( "aa" "ab" "aa" "ac" "aa" "ad" )
~> echo  "${IDS[@]}"
aa ab aa ac aa ad
~>
~> printf "%s\n" "${IDS[@]}" | sort -u
aa
ab
ac
ad
~> UNIQ_IDS=($(printf "%s\n" "${IDS[@]}" | sort -u))
~> echo "${UNIQ_IDS[@]}"
aa ab ac ad
~>
```

Comment: to fix the array I was forced to do this: `ids=(ab "a a" ac aa ad ac aa);IFS=$'\n' ids2=(\`printf "%s\n" "${ids[@]}" |sort -u\`)`, so I added `IFS=$'\n'` suggested by @gniourf_gniourf

Comment: I also had to backup and, after the command, restore IFS value! or it messes other things..

Comment: @Jetse This should be the accepted answer as it uses only two commands, no loops, no eval and is the most compact version.

Comment: @AquariusPower Careful, you are basically doing: `IFS=$'\n'; ids2=(...)`, since temporary assignment before variable assignments is not possible. Instead use this construction: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -a ids2 <<<"$(printf "%s\n" "${ids[@]}" | sort -u)"`.

Comment: Shell check says no: [SC2207](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207), better use `mapfile -t UNIQ_IDS < <(printf "%s\n" "${IDS[@]}" | sort -u)`.

Answer (score 19):

If your array elements have white space or any other shell special character (and can you be sure they don't?) then to capture those first of all (and you should just always do this) express your array in double quotes! e.g. `"${a[@]}"`. Bash will literally interpret this as "each array element in a separate *argument*". Within bash this simply always works, always.

Then, to get a sorted (and unique) array, we have to convert it to a format sort understands and be able to convert it back into bash array elements. This is the best I've come up with:

```
eval a=($(printf "%q\n" "${a[@]}" | sort -u))
```

Unfortunately, this fails in the special case of the empty array, turning the empty array into an array of 1 empty element (because printf had 0 arguments but still prints as though it had one empty argument - see explanation). So you have to catch that in an if or something.

Explanation:
The %q format for printf "shell escapes" the printed argument, in just such a way as bash can recover in something like eval!
Because each element is printed shell escaped on it's own line, the only separator between elements is the newline, and the array assignment takes each line as an element, parsing the escaped values into literal text.

e.g.

```
> a=("foo bar" baz)
> printf "%q\n" "${a[@]}"
'foo bar'
baz
> printf "%q\n"
''
```

The eval is necessary to strip the escaping off each value going back into the array.

Comment: This is the only code that worked for me because my array of strings had spaces. The %q is what did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: And if you don't want to alter the order of the elements, use `uniq` instead of `sort -u`.

Comment: Note that `uniq` does not work properly on unsorted lists, so it must always be used in combination with `sort`.

Comment: uniq on an unsorted list will remove *consecutive* duplicates. It will not remove identical list elements separated by something else inbetween. uniq may be useful enough depending on the expected data and the desire to maintain original order.

Comment: Can someone tell me why I need `%q` over `%s`?

Answer (score 14):

'sort' can be used to order the output of a for-loop:

```
for i in ${ids[@]}; do echo $i; done | sort
```

and eliminate duplicates with "-u":

```
for i in ${ids[@]}; do echo $i; done | sort -u
```

Finally you can just overwrite your array with the unique elements:

```
ids=( `for i in ${ids[@]}; do echo $i; done | sort -u` )
```

Comment: And if you don't want to change the order of what's left, you don't have to: `ids=( \`for i in ${ids[@]}; do echo $i; done | uniq\` )`

Comment: Note, however, that if you don't change the order, you also won't get the desired result, as `uniq` only removes *adjacent* duplicate lines.

Answer (score 11):

this one will also preserve order:

```
echo ${ARRAY[@]} | tr [:space:] '\n' | awk '!a[$0]++'
```

and to modify the original array with the unique values:

```
ARRAY=($(echo ${ARRAY[@]} | tr [:space:] '\n' | awk '!a[$0]++'))
```

Comment: Don't use `uniq`. It needs sorting, where awk does not, and the intent of this answer is to preserve ordering when the input is unsorted.

Comment: Btw this example was made famous by this blog post: https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-two. What a fascinating awk one-liner

Answer (score 10):

To create a new array consisting of unique values, ensure your array is not empty then do one of the following:

#### Remove duplicate entries (with sorting)

```
readarray -t NewArray < <(printf '%s\n' "${OriginalArray[@]}" | sort -u)
```

#### Remove duplicate entries (without sorting)

```
readarray -t NewArray < <(printf '%s\n' "${OriginalArray[@]}" | awk '!x[$0]++')
```

Warning: Do not try to do something like `NewArray=( $(printf '%s\n' "${OriginalArray[@]}" | sort -u) )`. It will break on spaces.

Comment: Remove duplicate entries (without sorting) is just like (with sorting) except change `sort -u` to be `uniq`.

Comment: @JesseChisholm `uniq` only merges duplicate lines that are adjacent, so it's not the same as `awk '!x[$0]++'`.

Comment: @JesseChisholm Please to delete misleading comment.

Answer (score 7):

How about this variation?

```
printf '%s\n' "${ids[@]}" | sort -u
```

Comment: And then `sorted_arr=($(printf '%s\n' "${ids[@]}" | sort -u)`.

Comment: Same answer as @das.cyklone

Answer (score 5):

Without loosing the original ordering:

```
uniques=($(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"${original[@]}" | awk '!u[$0]++' | tr '\n' ' '))
```

Answer (score 5):

> cat number.txt

```
1 2 3 4 4 3 2 5 6
```

> print line into column: `cat number.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'`

```
1
2
3
4
4
3
2
5
6
```

> find the duplicate records: `cat number.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' |awk 'x[$0]++'`

```
4
3
2
```

> Replace duplicate records: `cat number.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' |awk '!x[$0]++'`

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

> Find only Uniq records:  `cat number.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i|"sort|uniq -u"}`

```
1
5
6
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a solution that only uses bash internals, you can set the values as keys in an associative array, and then extract the keys:

```
declare -A uniqs
list=(foo bar bar "bar none")
for f in "${list[@]}"; do 
  uniqs["${f}"]=""
done

for thing in "${!uniqs[@]}"; do
  echo "${thing}"
done
```

This will output

```
bar
foo
bar none
```

Comment: I just noticed this is essentially the same as @ghotis answer above, except his solution doesn't take list items with spaces into account.

Comment: Good point. I've added quotes to my solution so it now handles spaces. I originally wrote it merely to handle the sample data in the question, but it's always good to cover contingencies like this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Note that order isn't maintained in an associative array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161460/89484

Answer (score 3):

Another option for dealing with embedded whitespace, is to null-delimit with `printf`, make distinct with `sort`, then use a loop to pack it back into an array:

```sh
input=(a b c "$(printf "d\ne")" b c "$(printf "d\ne")")
output=()

while read -rd $'' element
do 
  output+=("$element")
done < <(printf "%s\0" "${input[@]}" | sort -uz)
```

At the end of this, `input` and `output` contain the desired values (provided order isn't important):

```
$ printf "%q\n" "${input[@]}"
a
b
c
$'d\ne'
b
c
$'d\ne'

$ printf "%q\n" "${output[@]}"
a
b
c
$'d\ne'
```

Answer (score 2):

All the following work in `bash` and `sh` and are without error in `shellcheck` but you need to suppress [SC2207](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207)

```
arrOrig=("192.168.3.4" "192.168.3.4" "192.168.3.3")

# NO SORTING
# shellcheck disable=SC2207
arr1=($(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"${arrOrig[@]}" | awk '!u[$0]++' | tr '\n' ' ')) # @estani
len1=${#arr1[@]}
echo "${len1}"
echo "${arr1[*]}"

# SORTING
# shellcheck disable=SC2207
arr2=($(printf '%s\n' "${arrOrig[@]}" | sort -u)) # @das.cyklone
len2=${#arr2[@]}
echo "${len2}"
echo "${arr2[*]}"

# SORTING
# shellcheck disable=SC2207
arr3=($(echo "${arrOrig[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')) # @sampson-chen
len3=${#arr3[@]}
echo "${len3}"
echo "${arr3[*]}"

# SORTING
# shellcheck disable=SC2207
arr4=($(for i in "${arrOrig[@]}"; do echo "${i}"; done | sort -u)) # @corbyn42
len4=${#arr4[@]}
echo "${len4}"
echo "${arr4[*]}"

# NO SORTING
# shellcheck disable=SC2207
arr5=($(echo "${arrOrig[@]}" | tr "[:space:]" '\n' | awk '!a[$0]++')) # @faustus
len5=${#arr5[@]}
echo "${len5}"
echo "${arr5[*]}"

# OUTPUTS

# arr1
2 # length
192.168.3.4 192.168.3.3 # items

# arr2
2 # length
192.168.3.3 192.168.3.4 # items

# arr3
2 # length
192.168.3.3 192.168.3.4 # items

# arr4
2 # length
192.168.3.3 192.168.3.4 # items

# arr5
2 # length
192.168.3.4 192.168.3.3 # items
```

Output for all of these is 2 and correct. This answer basically summarises and tidies up the other answers in this post and is a useful quick reference. Attribution to original answer is given.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh you can use (u) flag:

```
$ ids=(aa ab aa ac aa ad)
$ print ${(u)ids}
aa ab ac ad
```

Comment: The question was aimed at bash not zsh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get uniq values for first column in file

```
awk -F, '{a[$1];}END{for (i in a)print i;}'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
# Read a file into variable
lines=$(cat /path/to/my/file)

# Go through each line the file put in the variable, and assign it a variable called $line
for line in $lines; do
  # Print the line
  echo $line
# End the loop, then sort it (add -u to have unique lines)
done | sort -u
```