# Bash - convert array to lines (for using sort & uniq)

Tags: bash

let's say I have an array that goes like this 
(a a b b b c c d)
I want the array to have only one each character/string (a b c d)
is there any way converting the array into lines so I can use sort & uniq without temp file?

thanks !

Comment: Not able to get what do you mean by `array into lines`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get unique values from an array in linux bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648410/how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-an-array-in-linux-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a curiosity, the:

```
arr=(a a b b b c c d)
echo "${arr[@]}" | xargs -n1 | sort -u
```

prints

```
a
b
c
d
```

and the

```
echo "${arr[@]}" | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs
```

prints

```
a b c d
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `printf` command.

```
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort | uniq
```

This will print each element of `array` followed by a newline to standard output.

To repopulate the array, you might use

```
readarray -t array < <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort | uniq)
```

However, you might instead simply use an associative array to filter out the duplicates.

```
declare -A aa
for x in "${array[@]}"; do
    aa[$x]=1
done
array=()
for x in "${!aa[@]}"; do
    array+=("$x")
done
```

Comment: You can also combine the `... | sort | uniq` into `... | sort -u`

Comment: Or `array=("${!aa[@]}")`.

Comment: <shakes head> Why on earth did I write that second `for` loop?

Answer (score -2):

```
 for x in a a b b b c c d; do echo -e $x; done | sort | uniq
```