# How can we get the union of two arrays in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've two arrays, say:

```
arr1=("one" "two" "three")
arr2=("two" "four" "six")
```

What would be the best way to get union of these two arrays in Bash?

Comment: Actual union (without dupes) or simply both arrays concatenated?

Comment: Actual union (without duplicates)

Comment: In zsh you can just use `typeset -U arr`, pretty sure there isn't such an easy way in bash.

Comment: @Kevin how to use `typeset -U arr`?

Comment: @denysdovhan `typeset -u arr; arr=(a b a c); echo $arr # prints a b c`.

Answer (score 12):

First, combine the arrays:

```
arr3=("${arr1[@]}" "${arr2[@]}")
```

Then, apply the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13649357/5447477) post to deduplicate them:

```
# Declare an associative array
declare -A arr4
# Store the values of arr3 in arr4 as keys.
for k in "${arr3[@]}"; do arr4["$k"]=1; done
# Extract the keys.
arr5=("${!arr4[@]}")
```

This assumes bash 4+.

Comment: No need for `arr3`: just use `for k in "${arr1[@]}" "${arr2[@]}"`

Answer (score 3):

Prior to `bash` 4,

```
while read -r; do
    arr+=("$REPLY")
done < <( printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}" "${arr2[@]}" | sort -u )
```

`sort -u` performs a dup-free union on its input; the `while` loop just puts everything back in an array.