# Find items common between two Bash arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I have below shell script in which I have two arrays `number1` and `number2`. I have a variable `range` which has list of numbers.

Now I need to figure out what are all numbers which are in `number1` array are also present in `range` variable. Similarly for `number2` array as well. Below is my shell script and it is working fine.

```
number1=(1220 1374 415 1097 1219 557 401 1230 1363 1116 1109 1244 571 1347 1404)
number2=(411 1101 273 1217 547 1370 286 1224 1362 1091 567 561 1348 1247 1106 304 435 317)
range=90,197,521,540,552,554,562,569:570,573,576,579,583,594,597,601,608:609,611,628,637:638,640:641,644:648
range_f=" "$(eval echo $(echo $range | perl -pe 's/(\d+):(\d+)/{$1..$2}/g;s/,/ /g;'))" "
echo "$range_f"

for item in "${number1[@]}"; do
 if [[ $range_f =~ " $item " ]] ; then
 new_number1+=($item)
 fi
done
echo "new list: ${new_number1[@]}"

for item in "${number2[@]}"; do
 if [[ $range_f =~ " $item " ]] ; then
   new_number2+=($item)
 fi
done
echo "new list: ${new_number2[@]}"
```

Is there any better way to write above stuff? As of now I have two for loops iterating and then figuring out `new_number1` and `new_number2` arrays.

**Note:**
Numbers like `644:648` means, it starts with 644 and ends with 648. It is just short form.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review. Good question though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we get the union of two arrays in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33153756/608639), [Array intersection in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7870230/608639), [Intersection of two lists in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2696055/608639), [Compare/Difference of two arrays in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2312762/608639), etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `comm` with process substitution instead of looping:

```
mapfile -t new_number1 < <(comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' "${number1[@]}" | sort) <(printf '%s\n' $range_f | sort))
mapfile -t new_number2 < <(comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' "${number2[@]}" | sort) <(printf '%s\n' $range_f | sort))
```

- `mapfile -t name` reads from the nested process substitution into the named array
- `printf ... | sort` pair provides the sorted input streams for comm
- `comm -12` emits the items common to the two streams

Comment: interesting.. never worked with comm before. learned something new today. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from codeforester's answer, I can think of two other ways of doing this:

1. Load the values of `$range` as keys of an associative array. The
   values will be `1`. Loop through each member of `${number1[@]}` and
   `${number2[@]}`, testing them against the values in the associative
   array.
2. Use codeforester's `printf ... | sort` trick, but pipe both the list
   and the range through `sort | uniq -c`, then grep for the
   duplicates.

I'm not sure if either one of these is an actual improvement on your code.  ... I would create a 'find duplicates' shell function, but otherwise your code looks solid.