# Selecting only non duplicate values from two arrays

Tags: unix

Suppose I have two string array a,b,c,d and e also a,b,c and d.  I want to compare both the strings and remove the non duplicate value of these strings. Could you find me something for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648410/how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-an-array-in-bash

Comment: in the above question, take a,b,c,d in one string and a,e,c,d,b in another...i want to remove unmatched character and show remaining string..

Comment: Make one array containing elements from both the arrays, then apply the technique in the linked question.