# tar with multiple directories: is it possible to replace duplicate input?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, gzip, tar

I am using the following command in a bash script for backup automation:

`tar -vczf /tmp/${get_date}BACKUP${get_user}.tar.gz ${backup_dir[@]}`

`backup_dir` is an array in which user input is saved (the directories that will be backed up). If user input is illegal, it defaults to `/home/$USER`.

The creation of a tar.gz works, but if a user types in multiple illegal directories, or if they chose to update the same directory multiple times, tar just backups all the files multiple times in the same folder, which makes it quite cumbersome to restore.

To avoid this, I am looking for a way to get tar to ignore duplicate input. Example:

`tar -vczf /tmp/TEST.tar.gz /home/michael /home/michael`

should be treated as `tar -vczf /tmp/TEST.tar.gz /home/michael`

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Sanitize the array, remove the duplicates?

Comment: Or this, as it were ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648410/how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-an-array-in-bash

Comment: @Jetchisel thank you, that is exactly what I need. Sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: @tink yes, that will probably be it. I didn't think about going at the problem from the array, which would have been way more obvious than what I was thinking of. I will accept the duplicate.

Comment: Good man, thank you.